# Magento 2: How to get related product image url

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am calling API for fetching the product details along with the related products, but in default API its only display the sku but i need to get the related product's image url also and display it in the same API call.

Answer (score 0):

using below API for the product Links: related, crosssell, upsell. Try with below APIs :

```
GET    /V1/products/links/types
GET    /V1/products/links/:type/attributes
GET    /V1/products/:sku/links/:type
POST   /V1/products/:sku/links
DELETE /V1/products/:sku/links/:type/:linkedProductSku
PUT    /V1/products/:sku/links
```

Comment: yea i know this but it does not provide image url which is my main requirement.

Comment: i am already using product api, in this api am getting related product details with sku but not image url : the api is 
rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=WCTHCMWOVA0000002.  "I need related product image url"

Comment: add this api in que, so we know you already tried with this api.

Comment: you get the product id than do via GET API call for product collection.